# How do I highlight my best GitHub repos for potential employers?

Tags: websites

I have a few projects on GitHub that I'd like to be readily visible to potential collaborators and employers. But I also have a bunch of of public repos that I've used for one-off document sharing, or for courses where I was required to submit work by putting it up on my account. It makes my repositories page look cluttered.

Is there a way to control the order that repos appear in, or to break them into subdirectories?

Solutions I know about:

- I can bump older projects to the top by pushing a trivial update, but that seems clumsy and requires maintenance.
- I could pay for the ability to create private repos, but there are some that I'd like to have publicly available, just not near the top of my page.

Comment: Just speaking as a user, if I visit a web page offering software to download, then I expect direct links to where I can easily see the software or download it. If it is stored in github then the standard practice seems to be to link directly to that project repo.

Comment: @Brandin Certainly; this is about when I'm linking to my personal page on github as part of my resume (so I'm offering myself, not a piece of software).

Comment: Just wanted to note that this question has received 5 upvotes and 3 downvotes, making this close to my most-voted-on question ever. None of the downvoters left a comment... I assume they think this is off topic?

Comment: If you want them to see specific projects or in a specific order, why not link them to a page that shows them how you like. After all your github repo list is not designed for that. It's just for browsing files etc. But this is not really specific to github. Same should apply no matter where you put your projects.

Comment: It's really not about the work-space, bit instead on how to use a tool in which will give the user an output that he can show to his potential employees.

Answer (score 5):

Create yourself a github organization to market yourself. Put the flashy ones in there. Still all free.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a personal web page and you are pointing employers to that instead of directly to your GitHub page, use that to sell yourself, that would include links to GitHub repos and explanations about the project.

When contacting a potential employer use your covering letter to sell the projects you think are not only great examples of your work but also relevant to the position you are applying for.

Answer (score 0):

Put the repos you specifically want to highlight on your resume, personal website, or account profile - usually you can reference just the repo.  Also mention your place within it.  Don't make the reader intuit the meaning of your contributions.  Give a description... for example:

> My Project (*link to project as hyperlink)* - Key contributor and code reviewer - I reviewed 75% of all pull requests, and did the initial development on 3 out of 6 of our most vital features:  feature A, feature B, feature C.  Also one of the top 10 individuals writing bug fixes for operational support.

I know of no employers who go to github directly for recruitment.  The times I end up in a github as a hiring manager looking for prospective employees, it's because the employee has already been referred to me by a trusted source, and I have the employees resume and possibly also their cover letter in front me.  I may go hunting on my own - if the employee references an open source project or if I have reason to be curious - but I'm more than happy to have the employee highlight specifically cool things that I should look for.  What I may do w/out a direct reference is check the communication streams and see if the person is nice to work with.